expo-font: PluginError: Plugin is an unexpected type: object
I'm using Expo SDK 51.
Dependencies (cleaned)
"dependencies": {
"@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.23.1",
"@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.7",
"@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.6",
"@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.12",
"expo": "^51.0.8",
"expo-application": "~5.9.1",
"expo-av": "~14.0.5",
"expo-constants": "~16.0.1",
"expo-device": "~6.0.2",
"expo-font": "~12.0.5",

}
App.json
"plugins": [
  "expo-localization",
  [
    "expo-image-picker",
    {
      "photosPermission": "The app accesses your photos to let you upload an image."
    }
  ],
  "expo-font",
    {
      "fonts": 
      [
        "./assets/fonts/Chivo-Regular.ttf",
        "./assets/fonts/Chivo-Bold.ttf",
        "./assets/fonts/Chivo-Italic.ttf", 
        "./assets/fonts/Chivo-Bold-Italic.ttf"
      ]
    },
  "expo-secure-store"
],

I'm getting the following error when I do npx expo start: PluginError: Plugin is an unexpected type: object
This is when copying the example from the documentation edited to have my paths. I was now importing them in runtime, but wanted to make use of the new feature.

The solution for this is to wrap the plugin in an array.
"plugins": [
  [
    "expo-font",
    {
      "fonts": ["./assets/fonts/nunito-sans.ttf"]
    }
  ]
]


You can solve this the same way you did with "expo-image-picker"
The solution is
"plugins": [
  "expo-localization",
  [
    "expo-image-picker",
    {
      "photosPermission": "The app accesses your photos to let you upload an image."
    }
  ],
  [
    "expo-font",
      {
        "fonts": 
        [
          "./assets/fonts/Chivo-Regular.ttf",
          "./assets/fonts/Chivo-Bold.ttf",
          "./assets/fonts/Chivo-Italic.ttf", 
          "./assets/fonts/Chivo-Bold-Italic.ttf"
        ]
    },
  ],
  "expo-secure-store"
],


You have to wrap each one in an array, including "expo-secure-store".

"plugins": [
      "expo-router",
      [
        "expo-font",
        { 
          "fonts": "./assets/fonts/Eight One.ttf" 
        }
      ]
    ],


Although this code might answer the question, I recommend that you also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.
